# Seleccionar imagen de la galería y guardarla en SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Tengo una duda, tengo este ejemplo de cómo guardar una imagen en SQLite que inserta una imagen en la base de datos.
Pero si yo quiero guardar una imagen de galería en la base de datos, es decir, seleccionarla y luego guardarla en la base de datos ¿Cómo sería un ejemplo funcional?

```
public void insertImg(int id , Bitmap img ) {   


byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img); // this is a function

insertStatement_logo.bindLong(1, id);       
insertStatement_logo.bindBlob(2, data);

insertStatement_logo.executeInsert();
insertStatement_logo.clearBindings() ;

}

public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: No es conveniente guardar en la bbdd una imagen o, en general, cualquier archivo. Lo mas correcto suele ser guardar el archivo en un directorio, y luego guardar en la bbdd la referencia del directorio y el nombre del archivo.

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir la galería y seleccionar la imagen usa esto:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_SELECTED);
```

para recibir la imagen usa esto, aquí mismo mandas a llamar tu método que guarda la imagen en la BD:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PHOTO_SELECTED) {
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```